# I have a String of sentence and a list of words that need to be highlighted if there is an occurrence in that String. How do I do that

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring, spannable

I have a String of sentence and a list of words that need to be highlighted if there is an occurrence in that String.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Html.

```
 for(String word: listString){
           if(sentence.contains(word){
              sentence = sentence.replace(word,"<font color='red'>"+word+"</font>");
           }
     }
 mTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(sentence));
```

Comment: The final string is highlighting only the word from last item in list.

Comment: my mistake. string is immutable class.

Comment: So do I save the result in each iteration?

Comment: no.. each iteration will give the result of updated value. until all iterations are done you won't get final result. I have updated the code, use the same.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it with SpannableStringBuilder.

Here's the code:

```
@Override
public void renderFinalTranscript(final String transcript, String filler)

 {

getActivity().runOnUiThread(() -> {
   final Pattern p = Pattern.compile(filler);
   final Matcher matcher = p.matcher(transcript);

   SpannableStringBuilder sb = new SpannableStringBuilder(transcript);

   while(matcher.find()){
   sb.setSpan(CharacterStyle.wrap(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED)), matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
   }
    transcribeText.append(spanny);
});
}
```

I called this method in a for loop and got the intended result